# Дерево отрезков. Нахождение суммы и присвоение

Tags: c++

Решал задачу:
Дан массив из
N
элементов, нужно научиться находить сумму чисел на отрезке.

Формат ввода

Первая строка содержит два целых числа
N
и
K
— число чисел в массиве и количество запросов.
(
1
≤
N
≤
1
0
0
0
0
0
)
,
(
0
≤
K
≤
1
0
0
0
0
0
)
. Следующие
K
строк содержат запросы
“A i x” — присвоить
i
-му элементу массива значение
x
(
1
≤
i
≤
n
,
0
≤
x
≤
1
0
^
9
)
“Q l r” — найти сумму чисел в массиве на позициях от
l
до
r
. (
1
≤
l
≤
r
≤
n
)
Изначально в массиве живут нули.

Формат вывода

На каждый запрос вида Q l r нужно вывести единственное число — сумму на отрезке.

Пример:
Ввод

5 9

A 2 2

A 3 1

A 4 2

Q 1 1

Q 2 2

Q 3 3

Q 4 4

Q 5 5

Q 1 5
Вывод:
0
2
1
2
0
5
Вот мой код:

```
void update(int v,int tl,int tr, int pos,int x,vector<ll>& t){

    if(tl==tr)
        t[v]=x;

    else{
        int tm=(tl+tr)>>1;

        if(pos<=tm)
            update(v*2,tl,tm,pos,x,t);
        else
            update(v*2+1,tm+1,tr,pos,x,t);

        t[v]=t[v*2]+t[v*2+1];
    }

}

int get(int v,int tl,int tr,int l,int r,vector<ll>& t){
    if(tl==l&&tr==r)
        return t[v];

    int ans=0;
    int tm=(tl+tr)>>1;

    if(l<=tm)
        ans+=get(v*2,tl,tm,l,min(r,tm),t);
    if(r>tm)
        ans+=get(v*2+1,tm+1,tr,max(l,tm+1),r,t);

    return ans;
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);

    int n,k,l,r;
    cin>>n>>k;

    vector<ll> t(4*n);

    char c;

    for (int i=0;i<k;++i){
        cin>>c;
        cin>>l>>r;

        if(c=='A')
            update(1,1,n,l,r,t);
        else
            cout<<get(1,1,n,l,r,t)<<'\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Программа правильно работает на примере, проходит 4 теста, а затем выдает неправильный результат. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка.

Comment: лучше использовать восходящую реализацию, она проще пишется, но не будет работать с ленивым деревом отрезков, если интересно могу скинуть код

Comment: Да, скиньте. Но мне бы еще хотелось знать, что в моем коде неправильного.

Comment: Только что попробовал изменить размер массива t на unsigned long long и все получилось. Проблема была в переполнениях.

Comment: https://cses.fi/paste/be2e02ac86946f8628165f/